# map duplicates key value pair if not present

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

Following is my structure definition:

```
type test struct{
    Title  string
    State  string
    Counts int
}
```

I want to map struct object members in following way
`map[Title:map[State:Counts]]`

This is the code which successfully do so

```
func main() {
    r := make(map[string]map[string]int)
    r1 := make(map[string]int)
    var ts []test

    ts = append(ts, test{Title: "Push 1",
        State:  "Active",
        Counts: 20})
    ts = append(ts, test{Title: "Push 1",
        State:  "InActive",
        Counts: 20})
    ts = append(ts, test{Title: "Push 1",
        State:  "Checked",
        Counts: 20})
    ts = append(ts, test{Title: "Push 1",
        State:  "Active",
        Counts: 23})

    ts = append(ts, test{Title: "Push 2",
        State:  "Active",
        Counts: 20})
    ts = append(ts, test{Title: "Push 2",
        State:  "InActive",
        Counts: 23})

    for _, t := range ts {
        r1[t.State] = t.Counts
        r[t.Title] = r1

    }
    fmt.Println("struct: ", ts)
    fmt.Println("map: ", r)
}
```

Problem I am facing is Title "Push 2" which does not have a `State: Checked` is been appended with Count value of previous object.
Following output is as follows

```
struct: [{Push 1 Active 20} {Push 1 InActive 20} {Push 1 Checked 20} {Push 1 Active 23} {Push 2 Active 20} {Push 2 InActive 23}]
map: map[Push 1:map[Active:20 Checked:20 InActive:23] Push 2:map[Active:20 Checked:20 InActive:23]]
```

Code I compiled is in go playground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r := make(map[string]map[string]int)` only creates a single map, it has no entries.

`r1 := make(map[string]int)` also only creates a single map to count states, but you don't need only one, you need a separate one for each distinct title.

So instead of creating that single `r1`, create inner maps on demand. Range over your structs, and when there is no inner map for its title, then create one and store it in the outer `r` map.

Like this:

```
for _, t := range ts {
    counts := r[t.Title]
    if counts == nil {
        counts = make(map[string]int)
        r[t.Title] = counts
    }
    counts[t.State]++

}
```

Note that the counting operation may simply be `counts[t.State]++`.

With this the output will be (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/oto3PwltiOJ)):

```
map:  map[Push 1:map[Active:2 Checked:1 InActive:1] Push 2:map[Active:1 InActive:1]]
```